# How can we upload and user object and image using multipart image upload in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am working on an application where I have to upload user data like name, address along with the user image.I tried to find out whether I can upload user object (the way we pass during a normal request)with image using multipart upload but did not received any satisfactory solution

Comment: Can you explain more ?, you want to upload data to a server ? if yes then you need to use **HttpUrlConnection** or **HttpClient** classes, if i'm wrong please explain more so i can help.

Comment: I want to upload image and user object.Take for example Customer information form where you have customer data and image.I am not getting an example where I could upload direct customer object but they are passing data a single field like customer id,customer name and image data etc which I dont want.I want to achieve it using retofit multipart upload

Comment: I too am finding it difficult to find cogent examples of this seemingly common thing.  I've tried over twenty different sample programs--none have worked. :(